# Test if non-null property exists in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB collection with following documents:

```
{ }
{ name: null }
{ name: "" }
{ name: "My name" }
```

Is there any way to display if the non-null `name` property exists (even as empty string)? Desired result should be:

```
{ exists: "No" }
{ exists: "No" }
{ exists: "Yes" }
{ exists: "Yes" }
```

My current query can only work with `{ name: null }`. For `{ }` it returns `{ exists: "Yes" }`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            exists: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {$eq: ["$name", null]},
                    then: "No",
                    else: "Yes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$in` with [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/index.html) to check the type of field, if field is not present then it
will return `missing`,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      exists: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [
              { "$type": "$name" },
              ["null", "missing"]
            ]
          },
          then: "No",
          else: "Yes"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j3XqqTmZkyI)